# How do i get the primary key of a sequelize model?

Tags: sequelize.js

Basically, given an instance or a model, I would like to 
a) Know if a primary key exists
b) know the name of that field(s)

Comment: I wrote an import script which was importing an existing database and generating Sequelize models while ago, I used `Model.describe()` and parse the result and find the primary keys, indices, foreign keys etc.

Comment: thanks! I will construct an answer based on your hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Soheil Jadidian's comment; the following snippet returns an array of primary keys found. Thus, it works with composite keys as well.

```
Model.describe().then(function (schema) {
    return Object.keys(schema).filter(function(field){
        return schema[field].primaryKey;
    });
}).tap(console.log);
```

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at Model.primaryKeyAttributes, it is array of string names of primary key attributes:

```
console.dir(Model.primaryKeyAttributes);

[ 'id' ]
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: @Catfish simply found it in Model, can't find documentation anywhere

Answer (score 3):

- Model.primaryKeyAttributes - array of names
- Model.primaryKeys - object with all the data